# How to show uploaded image in angular js 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a scenario in which i have to upload a image from my computer and show it in a image tag.i am able to upload image from my computer but unable to show it
in a image tag instead it is showing image name.i have searched in google but didn't find angular 2 or 4 solutions instead getting angular 1 solution.could someone help me on this regard

here is my code:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head >
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Upload Image</title>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="UploadCtrl">
          <img ng-if="image" src="{{image}}" alt="">
          <form action="">
              <input my-upload type="file" name="upload">
          </form>
      </div> 
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: This is not angular 2 code ..can you post the angular 2 code you have tried?

Comment: @Pavan correct me if i'm wrong so want you want is covert the code above to angular 2/4 code ?? like the syntax ??

Comment: Can you please paste angular side code here as well ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no angularjs2, i think you need angularjs code

You should use **[`ng-src`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)**

```
 <img ng-if="image" ng-src="{{image}}" alt="">
```

**`EDIT`**

I guess you need for angular2 then it should be,

```
<img *ngIf="image" [src]="image">
```

Comment: Hi sajeetharam, while using  that code i am getting this error:Can't bind to 'ng-src' since it isn't a known property of 'img'.could you help me on this regard

Comment: did you try as above